# grok pattern to get lines with particular word from logfiles in Logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-forwarder

I am trying to implement Logstash for logging few custom files, for which I have to get the lines containing the words : " out of swap memory". Following are the content of /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf file where in I have created custom_error type filter for the custom log files which I need to log to get the desired line :

```
 filter {
  if [type] == "syslog" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
    syslog_pri { }
    date {
      match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
    }
  }
  if [type] == "custom_error" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: requested %{NUMBER:int} bytes for promotion. Out of swap space?" }
      add_field => [ "received_at", "%{@timestamp}" ]
      add_field => [ "received_from", "%{host}" ]
    }
  date {
    match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  }
 }
}
```

But still I am not getting the desired result and lot of other messages along with required line are also showing up which is making the log message far too lengthy. 
How shall I  achieve just the required line from log files?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you can use conditional in your logstash configuration.
It is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) in the documentation.

So if you want to specifically filter lines containing the word `out of swap memory`, you can use:

```
if ([message] =~ / out of swap memory/) {
   ...
   only the lines containing  "out of swap memory" will go through this part.
}
```